# Sort C# keyvalue pair list into another keyvalue pair list

Tags: c#, list, sorting, c#-4.0

This is my list

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> lstRodsMonsterPool = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
```

Now i am trying to sort it like this but it is giving error

```
lstRodsMonsterPool = (from entry in lstRodsMonsterPool 
                      orderby entry.Value ascending 
                      select entry)
          .ToList<new KeyValuePair<string,int>(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)>;
```

C# 4.0

Thank you

Comment: "but it is giving error" - the suspense....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.ToList()` doesn't take parameters.

Comment: obvious once you can see the whole line, but OK +1 !  ;)

Comment: thnx working perfectly. the person who knows and who not like "Mitch Wheat" is very obvious :)

Answer (score 1):

```
lstRodsMonsterPool  = lstRodsMonsterPool.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to sort the list in place, so you can use [the `Comparison<T>` overload of `List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
lstRodsMonsterPool.Sort((l,r) => l.Value.CompareTo(r.Value))
```